# Why does my AS3 document class constructor gets called in infinite loop?

Tags: actionscript-3

----------------         1        ------------------

Hello dear developper friends,

I'm facing a very strange bug: let me explain it.

I'm currently developping a E-Learning app in AS3, Trainings come in the form of FLA Chapters, extending a parent class that we'll name "ChapterDefault".

Suddenly today, i have NO IDEA WHY, but ONE of my chapters decided that his Document class constructor had to be called infinitely (I place a trace on beginning of document class constructor, and it gets fired infinitely)

To be more precise :

I have a FLA (chapter) extending a parent class (ChapterDefault.as) 
so my document class (chapter.as) is like :

```
public class Chapitre extends ChaptitreDefaut{
    public function Chapitre (){
        trace("Construct");
        super();
    }
}
```

Result :

```
Construct
Construct
Construct
Construct
...
```

Please i've been pulling my hair for 5 hours now, any clue or advice is good to be taken.
Thanks in advance, Don't hesitate to ask me more details.

And sorry for my english if it's strange ^^

----------------         2        ------------------

ChapterDefault is a VERY BIG class (around 1.5k lines), so i'm not gonna put it here ^^ And I really don't think it comes from it 'cause every other chapter is heritatin from it without any problem.

Here's the constructor of it (it's french) :

```
public function ChapitreDefaut()
{
    MonsterDebugger.initialize(this);

    if(ChargeurFormation.charge){
        init();
    }
    else{
        // On récupère le fichier XML dans le cas d'une compilation isolée : 
        c_XML = new ChargeurXML();
        c_XML.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, erreurCheminXml);
        c_XML.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, chargementXmlTermine);
        c_XML.charge(new URLRequest("../../../init/init.xml"));
        MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Chargement du XML lancé", "Max", "Constructeur ChapitreDefaut", 0xFF00FF);

        c_PrefixeCheminRelatif = "../../../fla/";
    }
    // Nous sommes dans un chapitre, toutes les questions s'affichent dans un cadre :
    Question.AVEC_CADRE = true;
    // Ecoute des évènements
    this.addEventListener(CHAPITRE_PRET, lanceChapitre);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ajoutScene);
}
```

if you want another part of the code, i can give it too you.

Thanks a lot

----------------         3        ------------------

Thanks for your answer, but i don't think it's any of the 3 mentionned :

1) My parent/child classes are spelled correctly

2) New Instances can't be created ! "LesTypesDePression" is my FLA, with this previous code for document class, so i can't be calling it several times by ctrl+enter

3) In init() I just instanciate Sprites/shapes ect, anyways, you can consider ChargeurFormation.charge like a permanent false in this case, so that doesn't happen.

PS: I tried to remove the super(), doesn't change anything.

Comment: It sounds like A.A.Milne poem =) Please show us `ChapterDefault` class' code too

Comment: does it trace without calling super? as3 will automatically call super for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally solved my problem:**

it came from my shared library loading, i accidentally imported my chapter profile into my shared library, which had this exact chapter as document class, then while compiling this chapter, my shared library had access to his unwanted document class.

**Finally no bug, just a mis-use of the IDE**. Thanks for help still. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Wait - The name of the constructor/class ChapterDefault is in two different languages, depending on whether you're showing us the constructor for ChapterDefault or the constructor for Chapter.  Therefore the class/constructor is referred to in the actual code by two different spellings.  If this is your real code in both cases, then this is a bug.

In that case try changing the code in Chapter's constructor to use the French spelling, and let's see if that fixes the problem.  Maybe you have another class somewhere with the English spelling that has a problem in its implementation.

If that doesn't work, then it's probably one of these two things:

1 - New instances of the object are getting created over and over externally; please show us the code surrounding the declaration and instantiation of the Chapter object.

2 - The init() function in ChapitreDefault() is either creating a Chapter object internally or trying to invoke its constructor through some bizarre means; please show us the implementation of this as well.